# Is there a way to replace label text with image in Django form?

Tags: django-forms, django-templates

I would like to have something in forms.py like:

class myForm(forms.Form):
    a = forms.IntegerField()
    b = forms.CharField(label="my image.jpg
here")

And in html source code it should looks like:
    <label
for="test"><img src="{% static "images/image.jpg"
%}"></label>

Is that possible?


Regards,
yang

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few options...

You could set your label to label="" (Untested,   unsure if it would work... might consider using {}.format to get your string set).

Redefine a built in method for displaying the label. You could modify as_p(), as_ul(), etc or redefine label_tag(). The source code is [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py) where you can investigate. I think redefining label_tag is your best choice.